# PayPal Vault Data Migration

Tags: paypal, extract

I'm wondering what the process is to migrate vault data from Paypal to another payment gateway. Authorize.net has a 2 month wait plus a fee of $2000. Does anyone know that process of data extraction?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this is by downloading the transaction history. If their is a way to upload it with your new gateway, then you could do that. Like through an excel file. But there isn't a feature to extract it to another gateway.